# Python program to find the ln() of a number

Tags: python

I am using Python version 3 and I am trying to find the ln of a number. I wrote the following code but it says invalid syntax. please let me know what am I doing wrong.

```
import Math

k = Math.log(1.0062)
print k
```

Comment: `print` is a function in Python 3, you need to use brackets.

Comment: and `math` has no upper case letter